# Angular 2: Cannot find name 'Subscription'

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

When trying to set the type of an attribute I get the error `Cannot find name 'Subscription'`. From which package do I import it from?

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

// I'm missing an import here. Just don't know which package to load from.

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-component',
  templateUrl: 'my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private sub: any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
       let id = +params['id']; // (+) converts string 'id' to a number
     });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**Edit:** Provide a more detailed code example.

Comment: I'm following the Angular 2 docs. They often leave out crucial information that users then have to research and waste a lot of time - which is quite annoying tbh. I can write up a sample component if this helps. Give me a second.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You have to import it like this:

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
```

Take a look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html
and there are several plunker's linked in that documentation.

Answer (score 12):

in angular 6 and angular 7

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to import **Subscription** from "*rxjs/Rx*".

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs/Rx";
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, just that line should load the type

```
import {Subscription}  from "rxjs/Rx";
```

And we can use it as expected:

```
private sub: Subscription;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Angular 9, You can import subscription with the following:

```js
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/internal/Subscription';
```